# Tin Can API and courses

Tags: tin-can-api

I'm new to Tin Can API, I decided to begin with the tin can driver and i followed these steps http://tincanapi.com/driver-quickstart/ but what I can't find or understand is how can I add a pdf or a powerpoint to the content of the driver, I mean anything other than html files. I don't know if my question is totally wrong but anyways I would like to understand how can anyone add a course of any type if he can't add other than html files.
Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A PDF or Powerpoint would be a link inside of the HTML of the course to a file included in the package. Tin Can Driver is a product specifically designed to enable cross standard course building, so use it if you want to be able to easily support Tin Can *and* SCORM and/or AICC, etc.

If you are specifically targeting just Tin Can then you control how those things are used within the course. Tin Can doesn't really provide for the concepts of packaging and launch. The current de facto standard for those concepts is a set of guidelines published for implementing Tin Can in an LMS. CMI-5 is a working group developing those concepts into a specification.

Also note that in both cases a PDF or Powerpoint may or may not be playable directly in the browser, and for either case you will need to implement the hooks into their interfaces to call the JavaScript API.

HTH.